# Open3.popen2e hangs when executing commands from Ruby on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, ssh

I'm using a similar script to do some setup tooling for my remote development setup in Ruby 2.7.2:

```
require "open3"
Open3.popen2e("ssh -N -f root@example.com") do |stdin, stdout_and_stderr, wait_thread|
  puts wait_thread.value.inspect
  puts "closed? #{stdout_and_stderr.closed?}"
  stdout_and_stderr.each do |line|
    puts line
  end
  puts wait_thread.value.inspect
end
```

On macOS 12.4 Monterey (M1 Chip) it produces the following output:

```
#<Process::Status: pid 76747 exit 0>
closed? false
#<Process::Status: pid 76747 exit 0>
```

But when I execute the same command on a Ubuntu 20.04, it hangs when `stdout_and_stderr.each` is called:

```
#<Process::Status: pid 13115 exit 0>
closed? false

 --> here it just hangs and does nothing
```

The same effect can be ovserved when calling `stdout_and_stderr.eof?`. It looks like no more output is comming, and it just waits for it but never finishes. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way in Ruby to tell if there is more output or not.

When using a normal `ls -lah` command for example, it does not hang. So it must have something to do with the ssh command. These are the versions I'm using:

```
# macOS 12.4
❯ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6

# Ubuntu 20.04
ubuntu@user:~/workbox$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
```

I can't really control the SSH version, as more people will use this tooling. I thought about using a timeout, but when a command takes longer to produce output, this could lead to some really confusing behaviour.

Comment: The only way Ruby knows if there's more output is if the handle has been closed, or if the process has terminated. If neither of those two things occur there *might* be more output, it just has to wait to find out.

Comment: You could try putting a `ctrl-d` into the prompt at that point and see if it causes the termination?

Comment: @tadman Does that mean, under macOS it closes the handle after the command finishes, and on Ubuntu it doesn't? Calling `stdout_and_stderr.closed?` returns `false` on both machines.